# How to apply input validation in React Hooks

Tags: javascript, reactjs, forms, validation, react-hooks

I am new to ReactJS Hooks. I searched out for a clear controlled form validation example but didn't get one. So I decided to write a simple question that anyone can easily understand it.

Assume I have a two input fields, type `number` and type `text`

```
const [values, set_values] = useState({first_input:'',second_input:''});

const handle_change = (e) => {
  let name = e.target.name
  let value = e.target.value;
  values[name] = value;
  set_values(values);
}

const test_validation () => {
  // I used to do it this way
  if(document.getElementsByName('first_input')[0].value==''){
    alert("first input is required")
  }
}

return(
  <div>
    <input onChange={handle_change} name='first_input' type='number' />
    <input onChange={handle_change} name='second_input' type='text' />

    <input type='submit' onClick={test_validation} />
  <div/>
)
```

Is it wrong to use pure JS to check the input's value and set conditions or is it preferred to use React validation forms?

I tried to set `required` attribute on input element tag so it can't be skipped but didn't work.

I need to `alert()` warning message for the required filed or `highlight` or `focus` on it.

Comment: @tksilicon he seems to have a pretty solid variable naming style convention that he's sticking to. It may be against YOUR convention, but YOUR way isn't THE way. `document.getElementById` is JS so it should work fine, although I can agree that part isn't a very good practice.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firstly, your update function isn't really working as it should.

Try this instead:

```
const handle_change = (e) => {
  let name = e.target.name
  let value = e.target.value;
  set_values({ ...values, [name]: value });
}
```

Then the better practice here is to make your `<input />` elements controlled components.

Eg for `first_input` do this:

```
<input onChange={handle_change} name='first_input' type='number' value={values.first_input} />
```

Then your validation could look like this:

```
const test_validation () => {
  if(values.first_input === ''){
    alert("first input is required")
  }
}
```

This should successfully trigger the `alert` you were hoping for when the `value` is still an empty string.

Comment: thank you, this worked, please consider up-voting the question so it can reach out for those who have similar issues

Answer (score 2):

Your method of updating input values in the handle_change function is wrong. Values is a constant and cannot be modified directly. Use the ES6 spread operator with set_values to update the values.

```
set_values({...values, [name]:value});
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is a minimal example about how to handle validation:

Most of the time, you won't need to directly manipulate DOM API with React. Also make sure you do an `e.preventDefault` when you validate, otherwise the event will propagate due to [event bubbling](https://javascript.info/bubbling-and-capturing)

```js
import React, { useState } from "react";

export default function App() {
  const [values, setValues] = useState({ numberInput: "", textInput: "" });

  const validation = e => {
    if (values.numberInput === '' || !values.textInput) {
      e.preventDefault();
      alert("numberInput and textInput are required");
    }
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <form
        onSubmit={e => {
          e.preventDefault();
          alert("submit ");
        }}
      >
        <input
          onChange={({ target }) => setValues({ numberInput: target.value })}
          name="numberInput"
          type="number"
        />
        <input
          onChange={({ target }) => setValues({ textInput: target.value })}
          name="textInput"
          type="text"
        />

        <input type="submit" onClick={validation} />
      </form>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: `if (!values.numberInput || values.textInput)` translates to "if numberInput is undefined" OR "if textInput exists (even as an empty string)", "then do something".

Comment: Concerning `e.preventDefault()` if the form validation is ok we should just propagate the event. I guess

Comment: That still doesn't cut it. Because `!values.numberInput` is not the same as `values.numberInput.length > 0`. `!values.numberInput` checks if `values.numberInput` is `undefined`. In this case, `values.numberInput` is `''` (an empty string), which is NOT `undefined`.

Comment: Fair enough you're correct about the `e.preventDefault()`.

Comment: tl:dr; This is what you want: `if (values.numberInput === '' || values.textInput === "")`